# Is this necessry to learn ros for ros 2?

Tags: ros-bouncy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For understanding of ROS2 real time. Is need to learn ROS .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327456/is-this-necessry-to-learn-ros-for-ros-2?/) by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theoretically it should not be required to learn ROS before diving into ROS2, but I would strongly recommend it.

ROS2 is still quite new so there are not too many resources available that will teach you everything about ROS2 from the point of view of someone who does not know ROS.

This tutorial from Erle Robotics is one of the few that covers the basic of ROS2 without requiring ROS.
http://docs.erlerobotics.com/robot_operating_system/ros2

However, it's definitely not as complete as the official ROS tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/

Note that from the user application point of view, most of the basic concepts are the same between ROS and ROS2. At a first glance it may appear that only the APIs have changed (even if also the recommended design patterns are).
For this reason, given the current state of ROS2 (perfectly working, but under heavy development) also the official ROS2 tutorials focus only on highlighting the differences between ROS and ROS2.
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on 2019-07-03**:
Thanks for help.
And yes there are not may resource available that will clear the concepts ofROS2 and I also have lots
of confusion in RTPS and how to use ROS2 as real time. So now I am trying clear basic ROS concept using rasp berry pi 3 hardware. I think ROS kinetic has better resources.

**Comment by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on 2019-07-03**:
And it is possible to use ROS in real time(hard realtime) application.
Please suggest me.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-07-03**:
One of the reason for the creation of ROS2 is the enhanced support for real time. I would look directly to ROS2 resources for this specific topic.
Here you find a ROS2 tutorial about it, with code examples. https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Real-Time-Programming/

**Comment by [prajyot](https://answers.ros.org/users/41967/prajyot/) on 2019-07-05**:
I think ROS2 has not full support to embedded system. It will not support all type of controller and sensors.